# Google Apps Script to email sheet as a PDF working but want to clear some cells

Tags: javascript

I have edited a script I found to Email a PDF created from the spreadhseet to recipients in the spreadsheet. It is working as I need it to however I need to delete some of the cells before the PDF is created. What would the correct code be to add in to delete from row 194 or cells a194:j200. Code attached below.

Thanks for your help

```
// Simple function to send Weekly Schedule Sheets to contacts listed on the "Tutors" sheet in the Spreadsheet.

// Load a menu item called "Admin Tasks" with a submenu item called "Email Schedule"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Email Schedule", functionName:"tempsheet"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Admin Tasks', submenu);  
}

function tempsheet() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Please find weekly schedule attached. Contact office for any changes as soon as possible"; 
  // Get Project Name from Cell A1
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A1").getValues(); 
  // Get Reporting Period from Cell B3
  var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("F2:F2").getValues(); 
  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + " - Weekly Schedule Sheet - " + period;


  // Get contact details from "Tutors" sheet and construct To: Header
  var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Tutors");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 5, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Temporary Schedule");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);


  // Make PDF, currently called "Weekly Schedule.pdf"
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Weekly Schedule.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy 
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('copy of MASTERPLAN').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();



  // Delete the temporary sheet 
  DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work to clear A194:J200

```
var range = sheet.getRange(194,1,7,10);
range.clear();
```